# Game development: restart the sound(<audio> element) before it ended playing

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I ran into some issues regarding my small-web-game project:
 I have some sound files, given in HTML like this:

```
<audio id="shotSound" preload="auto">
    <source src="../sound/shot.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

the preload="auto" should load the content immediately on page init right?
Now I'm using javascript to trigger the sound when I need to (key press):

```
var audio = document.getElementById("shotSound");
audio.play();
```

This works, but  if I try to shot continuously or just faster(one shot after another) it won't work for shots after the first one. So, what happens if I hold the "shot" button: the sound is heard like it would be on repeat - which is obviously wrong.

Any ideas/suggestions are very welcome!
If I was unclear, please do let me know.

Thank you

Comment: I removed your second question because it's unrelated to the first. But feel free to ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the audio-tag into the HTML document. Preload the sound-effect in Javascript using

```
shotSound = new Audio();
shotSound.src = "../sound/shot.mp3";
shotSound.load();
```

Keep the shotSound variable in scope, so it doesn't get garbage-collected. Then, when you need to play a sound, create a new Audio object:

```
new Audio("../sound/shot.mp3").play();
```

It will play immediately because the sound-file will already be cached. And because it's a new audio-object, it won't interrupt other instances of the same effect playing in parallel.